# how to set a name for each tuple in a for loop

Tags: python, tuples

I have a tuple of tuples in the form:

```
test=((-1.0, 1.0, 0.0),
    (-1.0, -1.0, 0.0),
    (1.0, -1.0, 0.0),
    (1.0, 1.0, 0.0))
```

I would like to name each tuple in a loop as:

**Desired Output:**

```
coord1 = (-1.0, 1.0, 0.0)
coord2 = (-1.0, -1.0, 0.0)
coord3 = (1.0, -1.0, 0.0)
coord4 = (1.0, 1.0, 0.0)
```

Not sure how to implement this for a variable amount of assignments. i.e., my tuple of tuples has a length of 604.

Comment: `coord1 = test[0]`... for a fixed number of variables / assignments. For a variable amount of variables you should not do this, a collection like tuple or list is the proper data representation.

Comment: Do you mean something like dynamic variable creation? Because what you present is actually the assignment of each of the tuples to a new variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Comment: Hi. I updated my post. So yes, it would need to be dynamic variable creation.

Comment: You won't be able to generate code variables dynamically. You could use a dictionary as Sash and I proposed, and then use the keys as your pseudo dynamic variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this for more coord as you say you have 604 coords:

```
test=((-1.0, 1.0, 0.0),(-1.0, 1.0, 0.0),
    (-1.0, -1.0, 0.0),(-1.0, -1.0, 0.0),
    (1.0, -1.0, 0.0),(1.0, -1.0, 0.0),
    (1.0, 1.0, 0.0),(1.0, 1.0, 0.0))

coors = map(lambda x: f'Coords {x}', range(len(test)))

res = zip(coors, test)

print(*(map(lambda x: f'{x[0]} = {x[1]}', res)), sep = '\n')
```

Output:

```
Coords 0 = (-1.0, 1.0, 0.0)
Coords 1 = (-1.0, 1.0, 0.0)
Coords 2 = (-1.0, -1.0, 0.0)
Coords 3 = (-1.0, -1.0, 0.0)
Coords 4 = (1.0, -1.0, 0.0)
Coords 5 = (1.0, -1.0, 0.0)
Coords 6 = (1.0, 1.0, 0.0)
Coords 7 = (1.0, 1.0, 0.0)
```

Edit base comments:

```
test=((-1.0, 1.0, 0.0),(-1.0, 1.0, 0.0),
    (-1.0, -1.0, 0.0),(-1.0, -1.0, 0.0),
    (1.0, -1.0, 0.0),(1.0, -1.0, 0.0),
    (1.0, 1.0, 0.0),(1.0, 1.0, 0.0))

coors = list(map(lambda x: f'Coords_{x}', range(len(test))))


for i in range(len(coors)):
    globals()[coors[i]] = test[i]
    
print(Coords_0)
print(Coords_5)
```

Output:

```
(-1.0, 1.0, 0.0)
(1.0, -1.0, 0.0)
```

Comment: @l'mahdi: I would like to accept this answer as I like the lambda function usage. Thanks everyone for your input.

Comment: This answer is legitimate and actually ok. But one thing I don't like about it is that it is like the same with extra steps. Many python programmers catch these "cool" implementations and then go around complaining about python being so slow. As I wrote, the answer is ok, I would just not suggest such solution for the problem at hands.

Comment: @I'mahdi: How would I assign this output result to a variable instead of using print?

Comment: @user9106985, do you want this : `dict(zip(coors, test))`

Comment: not a dictionary but a list preferably. I tried res1 = list(zip(coors,test)) but it gives me Coords 0 as 'Coords 0' ie inside qoutes

Comment: can you send me an example, what do you want exactly?

Comment: essentially, I need to export exactly what is shown in the output of your solution to a external program.

Comment: @user9106985, edited. Are you wanting this?

Answer (score 1):

The question is ambiguous. What exactly is assigning a name? Mapping each of the tuples to a given string? Then you could map the tuples via a dictionary as:

```
{f'coord{x}': tup for x, tup in enumerate(test)}
```

Answer (score -1):

Create each tuple into a key-value pair using `dictionary`:

```py
test = ((-1.0, 1.0, 0.0),
        (-1.0, -1.0, 0.0),
        (1.0, -1.0, 0.0),
        (1.0, 1.0, 0.0))

coords = dict()

for i in range(len(test)):
    coord = test[i]
    coords[f"coord {i + 1}"] = coord

print(coords)
```

Comment: This is not answering the question.

Comment: @deponovo Check the edited solution, You can loop through the tuple and make each tuple a value and coord`n` the key and store it in dictionary

Comment: This actually what I needed. Thanks @SidharthMudgil

Comment: This novel version is ok. But it is not different in content from other proposed answers. Seems the OP is particularly satisfied with this version anyway.

Comment: @deponovo OP means?

Comment: Original poster (who asked the question)